# Add multi line text area to image

Tags: ios, image-processing, xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-text

Basically, I want to add an area with an arbitrary text to an image. So the image size get's bigger afterwards. This is what I've come up with:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        string filename = "TestImage.jpg";
        string bundlePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        string sourcePath = Path.Combine(bundlePath, filename);
        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string destinationPath = Path.Combine(docPath, filename);
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);

        string testString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
        this.AddTextToImage(testString, destinationPath);

        var imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 500, 500));
        imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile(destinationPath);
        this.View.AddSubview(imageView);
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }


    public void AddTextToImage(string texttoadd, string filepath)
    {
        UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(filepath);
        nfloat fontSize = 16;

        nfloat fWidth = image.Size.Width;
        nfloat fHeight = image.Size.Height;
        nfloat textWidth;
        nfloat textHeight;

        CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();

        UIFont font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", fontSize);
        NSParagraphStyle style = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
        style.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        NSAttributedString attributedString = new NSAttributedString(texttoadd, font: font, foregroundColor: UIColor.Blue, paragraphStyle: style);
        CGRect stringSize = attributedString.GetBoundingRect(new CGSize(fWidth, double.MaxValue), NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading, null);
        textWidth = (nfloat)Math.Ceiling(stringSize.Width);
        textHeight = (nfloat)Math.Ceiling(stringSize.Height);

        nfloat fullWidth = fWidth;
        nfloat fullHeight = fHeight + textHeight;
        UIImage composition;

        using (CGBitmapContext ctx = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, (nint)fullWidth, (nint)fullHeight, 8, 4 * (nint)fullWidth, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
        {
            CGRect frameRect = new CGRect(0, 0, fullWidth, fullHeight);

            ctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Yellow.CGColor);
            ctx.FillRect(frameRect);

            CGRect imageRect = new CGRect(0, textHeight, (double)fWidth, (double)fHeight);
            ctx.DrawImage(imageRect, image.CGImage);

            CGPath stringPath = new CGPath();
            stringPath.AddRect(new CGRect(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight));
            CTFramesetter framesetter = new CTFramesetter(attributedString);
            CTFrame frame = framesetter.GetFrame(new NSRange(0, attributedString.Length), stringPath, null);
            frame.Draw(ctx);

            using (var imageRef = ctx.ToImage())
                composition = new UIImage(imageRef);
        }

        NSData data = composition.AsJPEG();
        NSError error;
        data.Save(filepath, NSDataWritingOptions.FileProtectionNone, out error);
    }
}
```

Currently, I have the following issues:

- Text is cropped (e.g. `fontSize = 160;`). Multi line text seems not working.
- Text isn't shown at all (e.g. `fontSize = 16;`).

You can provide answers in Objective-C, Swift or C# - I'll try to translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the font was the problem. Using

```
UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize);
```

now does the job without cutting off text. The only question remaining is, why?